# Will my Jalapeno produce peppers?

Tags: identification, containers, container-gardening, peppers, jalapenos

I've been wondering if my plant will be able to produce peppers in this container?

Also to my next question, is it really Jalapeno? (bought those on E-bay lol)
[image]

Comment: a bigger pot, and more sun will help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a plant can produce many chilli pepper in such containers: it is common to use small pots (especially for shops).

But for me, the plant is maybe too much watered and fertilized, on the other hand, it is still a seedling, so it could be ok.

An other worry from me is about your location (windows with condensation?): if it is fall and cold (and not much sun), you may have few flowers (and so peppers) until springs.

Comment: it's outside the window ,it gets a few hours in the sun ,and it's still kind of hot (living in israel)